# Retrieve emails from other IMAP accounts in Gmail *automatically*

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3

I'd like to retrieve emails from other IMAP accounts (they can not be accessed via POP) automatically in Gmail. I know you can manually copy from one IMAP account to another and there are even IMAP copy scripts around but all this is not really what I'm looking for. I was more thinking of some kind of IMAP --> POP service which then can be checked from gmail (as long as the only support pop) and retrieve the mails automatically.

Anyone seen something like this or has an even better idea?

Comment: What email company are you using?  Maybe there is an option to enable POP3

Comment: ... or to forward mails to another account?

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've come up with in this situation is to

1. Forward the emails from the "other" account to the gmail address,
2. Use gmail's "send as" feature to send as the "other" account, and
3. Set the default reply address to whichever address the incoming email was sent to, so that if "other@example.com" receives an email, when you click reply the email will be sent as "other@example.com".

Comment: And what would be the case if you dont have access to the forward options, eg.: company mail?

Comment: Forwarding from my university to Gmail is notoriously buggy (they specifically warn that their forwarding is bad). Have you found any better solution in the seven years since you posted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and wrote a little node.js script which sets up a POP server to shadow the IMAP server. GMail then polls the POP server. It seems to work reasonably well, although it may still be a bit buggy. http://github.com/addrummond/imask